How to reload custom dictionary in FreeRadius without restarting?
I'm working with FreeRadius v3 and I created a feature in my app that would allow admins to enter custom attributes, this would in-turn add these new attributes to a custom dictionary in /etc/freeradius/3.0/dictionary.vsa.
However, FreeRadius does not recognize the new additions unless I restart it and doing so would disconnect all users connected to it.
I tried using sudo radmin -e hup but it did not work.
Is there a way to reload the dictionary files without restarting FreeRadius?

I would try using the "service reload" command, as follows.
service radiusd reload

If the command above fails, try the "kill -HUP" command.
kill -HUP $(cat /var/run/radiusd/radiusd.pid)

If neither work for you, let me know. I may have some additional suggestions.
